# Business performance data of web company like number of employees, revenue etc

Tags: data-request, finance, web-crawling, business, companies

Is there a dataset describing the #employees, #customers, revenue, investment etc for web company such as google, mozilla, yahoo, facebook?

WIKI has few information like #employees, revenue. Querying SPARQL with DBpedia may extract it. However, the information is few.

Yahoo! finance has much more information, using Yahoo! finance API with company symbol (using fb for Facebook for instance) can extract this information if knowing the company symbol in NASDAQ stock market in advance.

But it has drawbacks. NASDAQ doesn't contain company outside the U.S and outside the stock market. For example, deutsch tekecom in the former case and Mozilla in the latter case. The former case can be solved by considering more than one stock market but it will face the problem of redundancy. Ex. Facebook in London stock market , Facebook in Germany stock market, Facebook in NASDAQ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to datasets (Excel spreadsheets) from a NYU professor whom has been keeping corporate finance data on major corporations for 20 years:

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/data.html

Filter the companies with classification "Software (Internet)", there are 759 of them. I generated the list at https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/1145776cc37d5654c310 but here is an excerpt:

```
Fund.com Inc. (OTCPK:FNDM)
SpectrumDNA, Inc. (OTCPK:SPXA)
Net Savings Link, Inc. (OTCPK:NSAV)
Global MobileTech, Inc. (OTCPK:GLMB)
Santeon Group, Inc. (OTCPK:SANT)
Anchorage International Holdings Corp. (OTCPK:AHCP)
myContactCard, Inc. (OTCPK:MYCT)
Metatron, Inc. (OTCPK:MRNJ)
Optimum Interactive USA Ltd. (OTCPK:OPTL)
Verecloud, Inc. (OTCPK:VCLD)
Bigsupersearch Com Inc. (OTCPK:BSPR)
Idle Media, Inc. (OTCPK:IDLM)
Thwapr, Inc. (OTCPK:THWI)
Bizzingo, Inc. (OTCPK:BIZZ)
Digagogo Ventures Corp. (OTCPK:DOGO)
Rarus Technologies Inc. (OTCPK:RARS)
SinglePoint, Inc. (OTCPK:SING)
WrapMail, Inc. (OTCPK:WRAP)
Eventure Interactive, Inc. (OTCBB:EVTI)
Guard Dog, Inc. (OTCPK:GRDO)
BullsnBears.com, Inc. (OTCPK:BNBI)
Truli Media Group, Inc. (OTCPK:TRLI)
Wally World Media, Inc. (OTCPK:WLYW)
IL2M International Corp (OTCPK:ILIM)
EFH Group, Inc. (OTCBB:TWYF)
```